# Setting background image on UIButton stretches button even though contentMode is set to ScaleAspectFit

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIButton and a UIImage. I am calling `myButton.setBackgroundImage` but this causes the button to stretch. Strangely, the button width is constant, but the height is stretched down. There are some constraints on the button, but I don't see why the button should change size. Help?

Comment: can you tell me exactly what are your constraints ? Try setting image instead of background image

Comment: There is no visible difference between setting the image and background image. There is a constraint on width and some other regarding relative position to other elements. But, given that the button size shouldn't change at all, it seems weird that the constraints should have an effect.

Comment: How have you set the contentMode of the button? Can you post your code. I think you may be setting the contentmode of the actual button and not the imageView of the button. so something like muButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to main its original size, use image instead of backgroundImage.

In case my assumption is wrong, and setting background image is causing the button to stretch, it's probably your constraints is not set-up properly.

Comment: You are right, the constraints were not set properly. After that, using `setBackgroundImage` worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *doneButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nearByBack"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonActon) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[doneButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 32)];
[doneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

just make setimage not setbackgroundimage, try if this solve your problem